# Как выделить отрезки кода с помощью регулярного выражения?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Всем привет, вот пример: https://regex101.com/r/yO2bD5/1

Проблема в том, что искомое выделяется от первого `<hr />` до последнего `</p>` выделяя при этом оба куска, в базе данных такая ситуация приводит к тому что в результат попадает вообще очень много лишнего. Каким образом можно было бы находить данные отрезки каждый по отдельности?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще так:

```
array_filter(preg_split('@<hr\s*\/>\s*@', $yourText), function($e){return trim($e) !== '';});
```

Предложенный текст поделится как надо и фильтром убрать пустые строки.
Если принципиально нужно найти регуляркой, то как-то так:

```
<hr\s*\/>\s*[\\n]*\s*(.+<\/p>)
```

https://regex101.com/r/yO2bD5/2

Answer (score 1):

Инвертируйте "жадность" квантификатора `*`, используя последовательность `*?`

```
<hr \/>[\\n]*<h3 class="brown art">Базовая[\s\S]*?и сборкой:<\/p>
```

В этом случае он будет захватывать не максимально возможное, а минимально возможное количество символов.